What is the best, easiest and most convenient IPMI remote console solution that works from Linux Terminal
I have two questions:

Is it possible to use IPMI remote console without Java? Anything like ipmitools, an alternative toipmitools?

Are there tools that can support Terminal / GUI access to IPMI remote console, an all-in-one tool, without Java, and can be run locally without using a browser?


Since Oracle stopped supporting JWS from Java 8 / Java 12, and there are bugs to run JWS / Java Remote Console from latest laptop / OS, it is really a nightmare for us to manage some old server module that are end of life.
In some cases, Java Permissions fail to work in order to launch the Console JWS on latest MacOS. Also there always some bugs involved.
For newer version of servers console suite, some of those support HTML5 Console which is a better solution, but we still have at least 50% of servers that don't have HTML5 Console. Also most of those servers we got from a dedicated server provider, so it's impossible to upgrade the IPMI suite to support HTML5.
We need a third party, maybe open source, tools to connect to IPMI remote console from our laptops. Something like ipmitools
Requirements:

Can deal with all IPMI console access, including those old IPMI suite.

Can support all brands, include but not limited to:

IPMI (SuperMicro),
IDRAC (Dell),
ILO (HP),
IMM (IBM / Lenovo),
maybe more?


Easy access and update regularly,

Would prefer can access to console through terminal, like minicom, a GUI application that support Linux, MacOS would also work.

Able to work with old servers which doesn't have the latest HTML5 Console. (and for some servers, we can't upgrade it to support HTML5)


References:

A Reddit thread that mentioned some options
IDRAC6-Virtual-Console-Launcher
Public (without Java)
Old ipmitools (but currently public archived, deprecated?)



Is it possible to use IPMI remote console without Java? Anything like ipmitools (In the other word, is there a good alternative tools as ipmitools?)

If you're asking about SOL (serial-over-LAN), then ipmitool (singular) still works fine, even if it isn't receiving any updates – because the IPMI protocol hasn't received any updates recently, either.
The other alternative is ipmiconsole from the FreeIPMI project.

Any tools that can support Terminal / GUI access to IPMI remote console, an all-in-one tool. (Again, without Java, and better can be run locally without using browser)

Graphical console (KVM) is not part of IPMI.
Even though SuperMicro likes to call their whole management controller "IPMI", in reality that's the name of a specific interface (local and network) that only provides very limited management – power, sensors, and serial-over-LAN.
So if you're looking for graphical KVM, that's generally very vendor-specific. Probably each manufacturer has their own protocol that only their own software supports, and I really haven't seen any projects on GitHub nor elsewhere that would attempt to reverse-engineer them.

Able to work with old servers which doesn't have the latest HTML5 Console. (and for some servers, we can't upgrade it to support HTML5)

HP iLO4 can be upgraded (although I guess iDRAC6 cannot), and when it comes to anything older... if you're still running servers with iLO3 or DRAC5, I'd almost call it retro hardware. And would perhaps use an accordingly old WinXP VM to run the management tools – not just for Java but also for the old SSL versions that DRAC5 wants.
One advantage is that such a VM would be portable between various host OS.
(We at work do have one ancient DRAC5 server as well, unfortunately, and one that uses iDRAC6; we use ipmiconsole for the former, and an unzipped Java JRE + .bat launcher for the latter. JavaWS is not strictly required as long as you pre-download all the files.)

Thank you for your answers. Mainly we need the access to the console so we can 1) see booting screen, and 2) install OS when needed, and 3) login to OS through root when SSH unavailable. So it's should be more like KVM / Console not really IPMI right? But Serial-Over-LAN should also work for same purpose. Is ipmiconsole good alternative for this purpose?

Most server firmwares output their early boot process to serial. Linux/BSD servers can also be configured to output their main boot process to serial and to provide a login prompt on ttyS1. Windows servers don't really show much anyway, but they have some kind of emergency console over serial as well. As for OS installation, several Linux distributions also support that over serial (I believe at least Ubuntu Server does), no idea about Windows – we just run the HTML5 or Java KVM when needed for that (but are you ever going to do a fresh installation on those old systems anyway?)

+ipmiutil. I found it correctly decodes certain BMC logs, like messages about memory module errors and PSU errors, while ipmitool can not. I also had used IPMI SoL console to access Windows SAC, which is very limited, but it can be still used to debug the misbehaving server, kill the offending process, or at least, gracefully shutdown the system. Console-only Windows sucks, but that's not the problem with IPMI SoL, which is great. And, @grawity, come on, any Linux can be set up to expose the terminal to the standard serial console, which is how the IPMI SoL looks to the OS.

@NikitaKipriyanov Sure, but good luck modifying an installer image to do so on boot. I'm not even sure if e.g. Fedora even has a tty installer in the first place.

I guess no sane person would use Fedora for servers? BTW, kudos to Proxmox team, they made the very compatible console installer, and it does configure the system to work with IPMI console the most convenient way, including the bootloader, which is often overlooked.

Some IPMI offer SOL (ie TTY port access) via ssh, I've done this on Dell and Supermicro, but Asus doen't seem to support it.
This is it definately my preferred remote command-line console, (when direct ssh is not working) because it supports seamless cut-and paste.

I noticed in some case SOL doesn't work well, like when I try to connect to SOL from macOS terminal with ipmitool, it can't even load the screen or sometime it'll give you a messed up text.
